# Time Series Data - How to

Tags: r

I'm thinking about doing a study over one month where the subject records how much he drinks and how often he urinates.

I want to get the subject to record these activities on a daily basis so that I have a month of data (times of urination each day, volume and times of drink taken each day).  Once I have a month of this data for one subject, I want to be able to compare it to similar data from other subjects.  The differences between the subjects would be weight, age, sex, underlying illness etc ...

I assume this will be done using time series software?  If this is appropriate could someone point me in the right direction so that I can crib the appropriate code?

So far I've found [Time-Series Data manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908057/time-series-data-manipulation) am I heading in the right direction?  I am only at the planning stage.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a tutorial or maybe an adviser. Planning an approach to a research project and figuring out the software to use for it is entirely too broad for an SO programming question

Comment: Please try reading up on how to ask a question, that can be answered by others: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Consider how to make a good example: stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/… and see how you can change your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use simple linear regression.  I'd recommend [An Introduction to Statistical Learning.](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)

Comment: Not sure simple linear regression is the way to go here. Time series data is usually modelled within some form of autoregressive ARMA/ARIMA model.

Comment: Yeah, but if you read the description of the experiment it's not really time series data.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure; he wants to record data *"on a daily basis so that I have a month of data"* and then compare this with similar data from different subjects. Sounds like time series data to me (with additional predictors). But given the sparsity of information OP has provided it's difficult to provide targeted and specific help.