# Indicating An Event on a Plot

Tags: r

I am studying patient fluid intake and frequency of urination.

I'm collecting volume and time of fluids drank and time of urination.

I want to indicate on a graph that has liquid intake when urination occurs.

Here's my data and code so far ...

```
time_log <- c("01:10", "05:50", "06:00","06:15", "06:25", "09:35", "10:00", "12:40",
              "14:00")
time_log <- paste("04/04/2019", time_log, sep=" ")
time_log <- strptime(time_log, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
time_view <- format(time_log, "%H:%M")
event <- c("u", "u", "T", "T", "u", "u", "T","T","u")
Volume <- c(NA, NA, 0.25, 0.25, NA, NA, 0.125, 0.625, NA)

patient_data <- data.frame(time_log, time_view, event, Volume)

total_liquids <- sum(patient_data$Volume, na.rm=TRUE)

plot(patient_data$time_log, patient_data$Volume,
     xlim = c(as.POSIXct("2019-04-04 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-04-04 24:00:00")), 
     xlab="Hours of Study", ylab = "Volume of Liquid Drank /L",
     main = paste("Total Liquids Drank = ", total_liquids, " L"))
```

This is related to the following question 
[Time Series Data - How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495685/time-series-data-how-to) which was poorly received by the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Try with `text`, `text(patient_data$time_log,0.4,"U",col=c("white","black")[patient_data$event])`. This will put a U at any point there is urination. Not sure if this is what you are looking for ..

Comment: That works for me, thanks.  I'd like to leave it open in case anyone comes along and says, "err, you don't want to do it like that ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `ggplot2` and dashed vertical lines. When adding the `geom_vline`, we subset the data for just the urination events (i.e., `event == "u"`).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(patient_data, aes(x = time_log, y = Volume)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(
    data = subset(patient_data, event == "u"), 
    aes(xintercept = time_log),
    linetype = 2
  ) +
  labs(
    title = paste("Total Liques Drank = ", total_liquids, " L"),
    subtitle = "Dashed line reprents urination",
    x = "Hours of Study",
    y = "Volume of Liquid Drank (L)"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) # just so we don't start the y-axis at 0.1 or something misleading.
```

[image: Visual]

Comment: I like the idea of using the dashed vertical lines, I'll look at doing that in base R with abline, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I used abline( v = c(patient_data[patient_data$event == "u" , 1]), lty=3, col="red") which worked well.  Do you want to amend your answer to include the base R answer?