# Base R: controlling xlim when time is on x axis

Tags: r

I would like to have the x-axis over a 24 hour period with xlim = c(00:00 of the day, 24:00 of the same day) with hourly intervals.  (Background [Time Series Data - How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495685/time-series-data-how-to) )

Below is the code for what I've got so far ...

```
### Data Input

time_Thurs <- c("01:10", "05:50", "06:00","06:15", "06:25", "09:35", "10:00", "12:40",
                "14:00", "17:20", "18:50", "19:10", "20:10", "21:00", "22:05", "22:35")
event_Thurs <- c("u", "u", "T", "T", "u", "u", "T","T","u", "u", "T", "T", "T", "T", "u", "W")
volume_Thurs <- c(NA, NA, 0.25, 0.25, NA, NA, 0.125, 0.625, NA, NA, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
                  NA, 0.25)
total_liquids_Thurs <- sum(volume_Thurs, na.rm=TRUE)
time_Thurs <- paste("04/04/2019", time_Thurs, sep=" ")

### Collect all data together

event <- c(event_Thurs)
Volume <- c(volume_Thurs)
time_log <- c(time_Thurs)
time_log <- strptime(time_log, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
time_view <- format(time_log, "%H:%M")

### Put into Dataframe

patient_data <- data.frame(time_log, time_view, event, Volume)

patient_data$time_view <- as.character(patient_data$time_view)

daily_plot <- function(x, day) {
  #    x patient data - a data.frame with four columns:
  #    POSIXct time, time, event and Volume
  #    date number of day of month
  #    y volume of liquid
  #    TotVol total volume of intake over week
  #    Event - drink or otherwise

  x <- x[as.numeric(format(x[,1], "%d")) == day, ]
  TotVol <- sum(x[,4], na.rm = TRUE)
  DayOfWeek <- weekdays(x[1,1], abbreviate = FALSE)
  # xlim = c(round(as.POSIXct(patient_data[1,1]), "day"), round(as.POSIXct(patient_data[1,1]), "day") + 60 * 60 * 24)

  plot(x[,1],x[,4], 
       #xlim = c(round(as.POSIXct(patient_data[1,1]), "day"), round(as.POSIXct(patient_data[1,1]), "day") + 60 * 60 * 24),
       # xlim = xlim,
       xlim = c(x[1,1],x[length(x[,1]),1]), ylim = c(0, 1.0),
       xlab="Hours of Study", ylab = "Volume of Liquid Drank /L",
       main = paste("Total Liquids Drank = ", TotVol, " L on ", DayOfWeek, "Week 1, Apr 2019"),
       sub = "dashed red line = urination", pch=16,
       col = c("Brown", "black", "yellow", "green", "blue")[as.numeric(x[,3])],
       xaxt = 'n'
  )
  # xAxis_hrs <- seq(round(as.POSIXct(patient_data[1,1]), "day"), round(as.POSIXct(patient_data[1,1]), "day") + 60 * 60 * 24, by="hour")
  xAxis_hrs <- seq(as.POSIXct(x[1,1]), as.POSIXct(x[length(x[,1]),1]), by="hour")
  axis(1, at = xAxis_hrs, labels = strftime(xAxis_hrs, format = "%H:%M"), las = 2)
  abline( v = c(x[x[,3] == "u",1]), lty=3, col="red")
}

daily_plot(patient_data,4)
```

My hashed out line beginning xAxis_hrs was my attempt to get what I needed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this one line:

```
xAxis_hrs <- seq(as.POSIXct("2019-04-04"), as.POSIXct("2019-04-05"), by="hour")
```

Comment: I find that this solution depends upon the input data set. One data set has 01:00 to 23:00 with hourly intervals in between but other data sets have 01:00 to 00:00 of the next day, How can I get more control over this parameter?